# Selenium Catch Javascript handled Error

Tags: c#, wpf, selenium

I want to Login through my program on a website. In case username or password is wrong I want to catch the Error Message (it's a Javascript Error like Bootstrap alert which change visibility after x seconds).

I started with the following:

```
browser.FindElement(By.Name("user[login]")).SendKeys(Username);
IWebElement element = browser.FindElement(By.ClassName("flash-message"));
if(element.GetAttribute("style") != " ")
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Error Message: " + browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='util-relative rsp-container']")).Text);
}
```

The HTML code of the Error Box on Start (without any Error):

```
<div class="flash-message notice" style="display:none">
    <p class="util-relative rsp-container">
        <a class="icon-close" href="" data-action="FlashHide"></a> 
    </p>
</div>
```

The HTML code of the Error Box during an Error:

```
<div class="flash-message alert" style="">
  <p class="util-relative rsp-container">
    Username wrong.
    <a class="icon-close" href="" data-action="FlashHide"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

The HTML code of the Error box after visible change:

```
<div class="flash-message alert" style="display: none;">
  <p class="util-relative rsp-container">
    Username wrong.
    <a class="icon-close" href="" data-action="FlashHide"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

I guessed that I can catch the inner Text of `<p>` with that line: `browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='util-relative rsp-container']")).Text` but instead of the inner Text I get nothing.

Comment: Try to wait for popup

Comment: I also tried using `Thread.Sleep(1000)`. Without success.

Comment: browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='util-relative rsp-container']")).getText() --> you should use getText() not Text method to get value

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascripts to get value :-

```
WebElement element = browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='util-relative rsp-container']"));
 String contents = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavascriptExecutor for getting all the attributes of Webelement and see for your error message in it like:

```
WebElement element = browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='util-relative rsp-container']"));    
IJavascriptExecutor javascriptDriver = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
Dictionary<string, object> attributes = javascriptDriver.ExecuteScript("var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;", element) as Dictionary<string, object>;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question to extract the error message **Username wrong.** you have to use *WebDriverWait* as follows :

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
var myText = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//div[@class='flash-message alert']/p[@class='util-relative rsp-container']"))).Text;
```